# Book suggestions for Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

I am an absolute newcomer when it comes to quantum physics. So kindly suggest me a book which covers all the fundamental ideas, equations and all such stuff related to qp, so that i can master the basics and then move on to the advanced stuff.Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a book that covers the very basics, with the math and worked examples to give you confidence, I would recommend Quantum Mechanics Demystified by McMahon.

He tries to show you by doing the calculations, possibly at the expense of providing physical intuition. But if you want to learn the basics of Dirac notation over a long weekend, this is the book.

My only real complaint with this book is the number of typos, basically it was never edited, or it seems that way, but it keeps you alert. My own copy is full of handwritten corrections.

The other book I found useful was by Richard Robinett:  Quantum Mechanics: Classical Results, Modern Systems, and Visualized Example, which covers more ground than McMahon, but also provides plenty of questions. There is a solution manual, but trying to get it can be awkward if you are not using it on a regular course.

The last book is the old standby: Schaums, Quantum Mechanics, which gives a 4 page summary of each of the main aspects of basic Quantum Mechanics and then does 10 to 15 worked examples.

If you look at the table of contents on Amazon for each book, you will see which suits you.

An online course, with a free e book, is given James Binney of Oxford, which is on YouTube. Leonard Susskind also has a 14 part Q.M course for beginners on YouTube.

Comment: No problem at all, but two things I learned were to take it slowly and absolutely definitely positively etc. etc......... Do the exercises. :) Best of luck with it.

Answer (score 1):

•David J. Griffiths, Introduction to Quantum Mechanics, 2nd Edition, Addison-Wesley Publishing Company, Reading, MA, USA (2004).
This is the reference book  Mr.Xue, my Quantum Mechanics teacher recommend to us,and I am really appreciated that.
The main feature of the book is that it starts with the Schrodinger Equation directly,but not with the confusing (particularly,extra) development before that,which I thought is thoughtful for the beginners.With the structure of this sort, it's more easier for readers to construct the basic concept of quantum mechanics.
Another friendly feature of content of this book is that not only the fundamental knowledge that appears in major textbooks about Quantum Mechanics will be covered but also some common exhausted questions that may arise during the learning in reader's mind will be contained too. It's amazing to find the resonances between you and the auther on the same point.
In summarize,I thought it is just book you are looking for.